# Ошибка при запуске exe: Failed to execute script (Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, arcade

Недавно я сделал одну небольшую игру на python с библиотекой arcade и мне захотелось упаковать её в исполняемый exe файл. Я решил воспользоваться pyinstaller, так как раньше раньше успешно пользовался им. Но у меня возникли проблемы, причины которых мне не ясны. И как это исправить я не знаю тем более. Когда я запускаю exe-файл, вылетает ошибка: "Failed to execute script main".

Я точно знаю, что причина в самом pyinstaller и в библиотеке arcade, которую я подключаю, потому что ранее я успешно компилировал другой проект тем же образом, и все работало.

Далее я привожу элементы проекта, которые, на мой взгляд, помогут разобраться в природе этой ошибки. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Подключение библиотек:

```
import arcade
import random
from math import sin, cos, pi, hypot, degrees, atan2, radians
import ctypes
import time
```

Файл .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Александр\\PycharmProjects\\spy-and-geometry-shooter\\main_exe.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\shooter'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)


a.datas += [('health.png', 'C:\\Users\\Александр\\PycharmProjects\\spy-and-geometry-shooter\\health.png', "Data"), ('background.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\Александр\\PycharmProjects\\spy-and-geometry-shooter\\background.jpg', "Data")]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='GeometryShooter',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False)
```

Команда сборки:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name=GeometryShooter "C:\Users\Александр\PycharmProjects\spy-and-geometry-shooter\main.spec"
```

Comment: Pyinstaler выводит такую ошибку(Failed to execute main script) когда натыкается на ошибку в самом коде А где в твоём коде ошибка это сложно сказать

Comment: Нет нет, в коде ошибок нет, без exe он запускается и работает, как надо